# searcing for the function calls submit_bio

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, block

I am trying to intercept the submission of io requests in the `submit_bio` for a project I do in Linux.

I want to find the main function that calls `submit_bio`, to submit blocks.

I believe that there is a function that takes a page and submits the blocks in it.

I am searching for such a function in Linux kernel that takes a page to submit and submits the blocks in it using `submit_bio`.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: As far as I know, block I/O is normally done by calling the generic_make_request() function and not submit_bio. The only cases where submit_bio is called translating a page to a bio are in the multiple devices driver (md.c) and in swapping (page_io.c)

Comment: @matthias.bgg, can you show me where the swapping uses `submit_bio`? I can't find this place in the page_io.c.
Thanks for the quick answer

Comment: What kernel do you use? I used linux-next and a simple string search in the file should do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either look at https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/A/ident/submit_bio and read the code around the references to submit_bio or use a tool like perf ( $(KERNEL_SRC_DIR)/tools/perf ) to get statistics on stacktraces. A simple tutorial to perf can be found here: https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial

Comment: http://lxr.linux.no/linux+v3.11.1/+ident=57428597 --> link doesn't exist. Could you share available link please?